# Async loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Well, I have the code below:

```
forEach(elements, element =>{
     if(condition){
        doSomething(element)
    } else {
       doSomethingElse(element)
    }
})
```

I would like make this in an async way, meaning the code waits until the operation performed on that element is completed before passing on to the next element.

I would appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: than you can not use a loop, sounds like you need to do some sort of queue. Run thought it, check to see if anything left, and move to the next.

Comment: are `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` themselves asynchronous?

Comment: Could use async await...

Comment: @Hamms Yes they are

Comment: @epascarello how to do a queue in js?

Comment: @TGarrett mind showing me please?

Comment: A list of promises or futures, then set to run in parallel, would be another async way.

Comment: It's not a good idea to perform a promise in a loop, instead push it to an array of promises, and call `Promise.all(<your_array_of_promises>)` after your loop. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all.

Comment: Aren't you actually asking for synchronous execution?

Comment: `on that element is completed`, for me it's about async, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I'll edit the grammar to reflect that then ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async / await`. Assuming your methods return a `Promise`, you can do this:

```js
const doSomething = () => {
   return new Promise(resolve => { resolve('do something done!') });
}

const doSomethingElse = () => {
   return new Promise(resolve => { resolve('do something else done!') });
}

const arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];

arr.forEach(async (item, i) => {
   let result = null;
   
   if (i % 2 === 0) { // or any other condition
       result = await doSomething();
   } else {
       result = await doSomethingElse();
   }
   
   console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: and assuming the engines OP supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you should avoid resolving promises in a for loop, as I said in comment you should store your promises in an array and resolve all of them after your loop. This should looks like this :

```
const promises = [];
elements.forEach(element =>{
     promises.push(condition ? doSomething(element) : doSomethingElse(element));
});

Promise.all(promises).then(...).catch(...);
```

This is only correct if `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` are async functions.

Comment: This is actually worked, there is one typo, it is `Promise.all` and not `Promises.all`, my concern with this is that Promises are not compatible with IE

Comment: Actually, you can use a third library or Babel for IE compatibility, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016327/how-to-make-promises-work-in-ie11

Answer (score 0):

`.forEach()` is already synchronous (meaning it acts on one element at a time), just use it as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Your syntax is a bit off, it should look something like this (`.forEach()` is called as a method on the array it is operating on):

```
elements.forEach(element => {
    if (condition) {
        doSomething(element)
    } else {
       doSomethingElse(element)
    }
})
```

Comment: In my case, it seems like `forEach()` doesn't know weather `doSomething()` or `doSomethingElse()` is done executing before passing off the next element

Comment: @fatah, you wanted _asynchronous_ code, not _synchronous_ code. I edited your question to reflect that. Glad you found an answer!

Comment: async code is non-blocking, whereas in this case, i wanna block the process while when an element is going through the loop and the function depends on the condition

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers provided thus far actually execute in the *one at a time* way you're looking for.

Promises invoke their executor function upon construction. So, by nature, in order to use `Promise.all`, all of your async operations must already be running. Think of it as `Promise.allAtOnce`.

@Daniel's answer comes close, but `Array#forEach` executes synchronously, so it still runs *all at once*:

```js
const wait = (time, message) => new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(_=>{
                  console.log(message);
                  resolve();
                }, time);
              });

let promises = [];
[3000, 2000, 1000].forEach(
  (time, index) => promises.push(wait(time, ++index))
)

Promise.all(promises);

/* 
    Even though `3000` was the first item, 
    `1000` resolves first because all the `Promise`
    executors run at once.
    
    Output: 
      3
      2
      1
    
*/
```

The most succinct way to execute *one at a time* is with an `async` loop:

```js
const wait = (time, message) => new Promise(resolve => {
                    setTimeout(_=>{
                      console.log(message);
                      resolve();
                    }, time);
                  });
    
const iterate = async _ => {
  let index = 0;
  for (let time of [3000, 2000, 1000]) try {
    await wait(time, ++index)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

iterate();

/* 
      Even though `3000` takes 3X longer to resolve, 
      the `wait` of `3000` resolves first, 
      because it is first in the iteration.
      Output: 
        1
        2
        3
        
*/
```

If you want to avoid using `async/await`, just chain the promises with a loop. This will produce the same result:

```js
const wait = (time, message) => new Promise(resolve => {
                    setTimeout(_=>{
                      console.log(message);
                      resolve();
                    }, time);
                  });

const iterate = _ => {
  // initiate with an already-resolved promise
  let lastPromise = Promise.resolve(); 
  let index = 0;
  for (let time of [3000, 2000, 1000]) {
  // chain each promise to the promise returned by the previous item.
    lastPromise = lastPromise
      .then(result => wait(time, ++index))
      .catch(console.error);
  }
  return lastPromise;
}

iterate();

/* 
    Even though `3000` takes 3X longer to resolve, 
    the `wait` of `3000` resolves first, 
    because it is first in the iteration.

    Output: 
      1
      2
      3

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt, using recursive function:

```js
var i = 0, n = elements.length;

function doNext() {

    // exit if all elements have been accounted for
    if (i >= n) {
        return;
    }
    
    var element = elements[i];
    i++;
    
    if (condition) {
        doSomething(element).then(doNext);
    } else {
        doSomethingElse(element).then(doNext);
    }
}
```