# How to fix 'Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'' error in IE11

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11, es6-promise

I'm trying to resolve an issue in IE 11, but I don’t know what to do. I am programming in new code style ES6 so I have to transpiling code from ES6 to ES5 (I use babel for transpile and rollup for bundling...gulp as task manager).

IE 11 reports this error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'
```

For understanding... Is an autosuggest search component. You can write something on input and my js component will send a request to a server (Promise) and server return json object with data.. then I process them and render a suggestion on the website.

I don’t know where is a problem. I thought that it was the problem with forEach method but I use polyfills so probably not (but maybe it is a problem with setup of my babel or rollup...I really don't know :/)

It is the most likely problem:

```
...
requestResult: function(_selector, _inputValue) {
        let self = this;
        let elRequestURL = _selector.dataset.service;

        let promiseObj = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            let requestURL = _inputValue === '' ? elRequestURL : elRequestURL + '?query=' + _inputValue;
            let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            let response = [];

            request.open('GET', requestURL);
            request.responseType = 'json';
            request.send();
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                _selector.classList.add('is-loading');

                if (request.readyState === 4){
                    if (request.status === 200){

                        var response = request.response;

                        _selector.classList.remove('is-loading');

                        resolve(response);
                    } else {
                        reject(request.status);
                        console.log("xhr failed");
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        return promiseObj;
    },
...
```

(If it is necessary, I can send the whole code)

Can it be the problem with Promise? Do you have any experience with this error or any tips how can I resolve it? Internet Explorer doesn’t show on which line is the problem.

Comment: `forEach` is nowhere in the code there... can you post where the `forEach` causing the error is?

Comment: add the code where you are calling `requestResult`

Answer (score 2):

IE browser not support the Promise object, if we want to use it in IE browser, we could use a transpiler (like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) to convert your ES6 code to ES5 code. Here is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016327/how-to-make-promises-work-in-ie11) about the promise object, you could check it.

> Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Object doesn't support property
>   or method 'forEach'

As we all known, IE9 and above supports Array.forEach but not for the NodeList.prototype.forEach(), more detail information, you could check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

If you want to use the forEach method in IE browser, you could add the following polyfills (before using the forEach() method).

```
        if ('NodeList' in window && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
            console.info('polyfill for IE11');
            NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (callback, thisArg) {
                thisArg = thisArg || window;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                    callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
                }
            };
        }
```