# Ie throwing SCRIPT1014 Invalid character after i've taken them out of my project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer

im using Vue. I made a website with promises & axios which works on every browser except IE. Vue seems to make promises & axios compatible for ie so i dont think that is the issue.

It says SCRIPT1014 Invalid character

When i click on the error in chunk-venders.js i see a bunch of obfuscated code like this

```
`(${
```

So i do a project wide search for backtick because they are not supported, i found 4 instances and i delete them all. I build, deploy and try again. Still blank screen with the same error. I cleared my cache in ie and restarted and nothing has changed. Where is the backtick coming from if ive deleted them all?

Comment: Could be coming from one of your node_modules dependencies. Often you need something like Babel or Typescript to translate modern JavaScript into something that older browsers (like IE11) understands.

Comment: Is there any way to determine which package it is?

Comment: Usually a bit tricky but you can usually click the error in IE11's developer tool console and it will try to open the file with the error, that might tell you something if you read around where the error is.

Comment: Please check your code, whether you are using the Template strings. From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), we can see the Template strings is not supported by IE. You could try to use """. Also, you could use Babel transpiler to convent the code from ES6 to ES5. Besides, since [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) doesn't IE browser, to use it in IE browser, please try to add the [Bluebird Promise polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016327/).