# 'Promise' is undefined on IE11 after reload page

Tags: javascript, promise, webdatarocks

with last version of webdatarocks and this minimal code:

```
<html>
  <head>
<link href="./webdatarocks/webdatarocks.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="./webdatarocks/webdatarocks.toolbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="./webdatarocks/webdatarocks.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id='output'></div>
  <script>
    TempDati = 
[
    {
        "Product": "Apple",
        "Price": 2.50
    },
    {
        "Product": "Cherry",
        "Price": 5.25
    }
];
var pivot = new WebDataRocks({
    container: "#output",
    toolbar: true,
    report: {
        dataSource: {
            data: TempDati
        }
    }
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I load this page in IE11 or when I reload the page with F5 I'm getting this error:
**SCRIPT5009: 'Promise' non è definito
webdatarocks.js (2101,654)**
After the error,  pivot table is drawed and it seams ok and functioning. In IE11 the error is visible only with F12.
How can i fix it?
did I have forgot some library to include?
Thank's for your answer.

Comment: You need to polyfill Promise for IE11 (3rd party module). Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016327/how-to-make-promises-work-in-ie11

Comment: Thank you. Fixed, I've added polyfill.io library in my script sections. https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?features=es5,es6,es7&flags=gated