# is it possible an iteration with asynchronous methods in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, struts2

I have a JSP with a Struts 2 include:

```
<div id="data">
  <s:include value="list.jsp"/>
</div>
```

list.jsp has an iterator inside.

With JavaScript I have 3 functions that make an Ajax call to different actions and web services but the 3 functions refresh the same Java object list:

```
function firstCall(product) {
    // an ajax call 
    .done(function(html) {
      $("#data").append(html);
    });
}

function secondCall(product) {
    // an ajax call 
    .done(function(html) {
      $("#data").append(html);
    });
}

function thirdCall(product) {
    // an ajax call 
    .done(function(html) {
      $("#data").append(html);
    });
}
```

And i have another function that  iterate a string array of products:

```
function iterate(productos){
    for(i=0;i<productos.length;i++){
        firstCall(productos[i]);
        secondCall(productos[i]);
        thirdCall(productos[i]);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need these three methods to be asynchronous because each takes like 10 seconds. =(

There is a better way to do this?

Comment: Better than what? It's not clear what the issue is: you're already doing async calls; `firstCall` returns and `secondCall` starts before `firstCall`'s request has completed. What's the issue? Do you need to wait for all of them to be done before doing the DOM manipulation?

Comment: Why don't you call *once* every function (passing the whole array) instead of calling a huge amount of times every function (passing a single element) ? You'd have 3 calls no matter how many elements, against n*3... Just saying

Comment: the product will always be a long 3.  So with the first product i need 3async calls but i don't know how to do it. when the 3calls finish go to the next product.

Answer (score 0):

If you do NOT care about older browsers (who doesn't support ES6) you can use promises.
It would become

```
new Promise(firstCall(productos[i]));
new Promise(seccondCall(productos[i]));
new Promise(thirdCall(productos[i]));
//You can add .then(function(){"code"}) to do something after it's done.
```

And your methods should have two new parameters: resolve and reject, that are functions that resolve or reject the promise. So .then works.

If you care about older browsers you can use another implementation https://www.promisejs.org/ or see [is there a way to implement promises in ie9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835687/is-there-a-way-to-implement-promises-in-ie9)

> See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for reference

Comment: sorry but i need ie9  ='(

Comment: There are many ways to do promises outside of ES6. Like using jQuery deferreds.

Comment: @ernstr I edit it to add a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835687/is-there-a-way-to-implement-promises-in-ie9 where it explains how to use promises in IE9 or even IE6+ ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/27839398/5776498 )