# jQuery 3.0 promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-3

What do you think about the following?

```
var starter;
starter = $.Deferred();

starter.then(function () {
    console.log('promiseOne done');
});

starter.resolve();

var now=new Date().getTime();
var stop=now+5000;
while (stop>new Date().getTime()){}
console.log('main thread finished');
```

In j*Query-1.11.1*, we get:

```
promiseOne done
main thread finished
```

which is **obviously wrong** and in *jQuery 3.0*, we get:

```
main thread finished
promiseOne done
```

which is hopefully what we expect, **since promise callbacks are executed asynchronously**.

However, by replacing **.then** with **.done**, in both cases I am getting:

```
promiseOne done
main thread finished
```

What is going on here? **Is that still a bug of jQuery 3.0 or .done callbacks are executed synchronously?**

Comment: Read this [blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/14/jquery-3-0-beta-released/) there are some changes in the defered object.

Comment: no mention of `.done` - perhaps they've spent all their time making Deferred.then Promise/A+ compliant and didn't give a monkeys about all the other cruft they put on Deferred

Comment: @JaromandaX fwiw, attempted to query this, that is the differences between `.done()` and `.then()` , at jquery irc today; the responses, in general, is that the spec only requires a `.then()` method, and that `.done()` should not be considered equivalent to `.then()` . http://irc.jquery.org/%23jquery/latest.log.html

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `.done` as long as you can except in order to terminate promise chains appropriately. `.done` is not specified in Promises/A+ so there are no issues regarding it.

The promise callbacks are executed asynchronously in order to [fix inherent problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744612/problems-inherent-to-jquery-deferred-jquery-1-x-2-x) in the previous design.

Comment: I'd like you to have a look at my [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362458/animations-under-single-threaded-javascript) in which no one gave me a good answer. I am considering you an expert in promises and you may answer it...

Comment: I've posted an answer @ILIAS - let me know if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: So, what do you think about .done callbacks? Are they executed synchronously or not? By the way, thank you for your immediate response to my bounty.