# Javascript Promises: Can they be fully implemented in userspace code?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, userspace

Is the Javascript `Promise` class something one could implement fully in userspace code, without requiring any support from native code (i.e., the Javascript internals) that only someone implementing a Javascript engine (such as the V8 team) would have access to?

Note that I'm not talking about implementing a higher-level abstraction library or module around the existing Javascript `Promise` class (say, to make it user-friendlier); rather, I'm talking about an entirely new, replacement promise implementation, say, `MyPromise`, with identical semantics as `Promise`.

I tried reading the relevant `Promise` section in the ES6 spec to get my answer, but found the spec very hard to read.

Comment: Of course they can be, and have been many times. Why wouldn't they be able to be?

Comment: https://www.promisejs.org/implementing/

Comment: +1. Well, that's exactly what I wanted to confirm. The mutex/lock primitive in C/C++/Java, e.g., rely on support from the underlying VM/OS, so I didn't know if `Promise` too was relying on some such native support from the Javascript engine's C implementation linking ultimately to the OS.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772801/basic-javascript-promise-implementation-attempt/23785244#23785244

Comment: I'd argue that the general answer is *no*, because there doesn't seem to be a standard user facing API to add something to the job queue. However, most environments implement `setTimeout` with which this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the JavaScript Promise class something one could implement fully in userspace code, without requiring any support from native code?

Yes.

The prime example is [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).