# Understanding setTimeout and its implementation in JavaScript Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, es6-promise

I have the following code:

```
function MyPromise(configFunction) {
  let nextSuccessCallBack = undefined;
  let nextResolve = undefined;
  configFunction(function(message){
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(nextSuccessCallBack) {
        var result = nextSuccessCallBack(message);
        if(result && result.then) {
          result.then(nextResolve);
        } else {
          nextResolve && nextResolve(result);
        }
      }
    })
  });

  return {
    then: function(successCallback) {
      nextSuccessCallBack = successCallback;
      return new MyPromise(function(resolve) {
        nextResolve = resolve;
      })
    }
  }
}

new MyPromise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('new message');
}).then(function(message) {
  console.log(message);
  return 'another message'
}).then(function(message) {
  console.log(message)
  console.log('here')
})
```

In this example, it seems that the `nextSuccessCallBack` is set to be the callback functions within `.then`, then its value within the setTimeout function is now populated. However, this confuses me. I thought that when we reach the `return` statement in the constructor, we return the object and effectively stop the function? If that the case then how does the program even get to the `setTimeout`?

Comment: `configFunction` is called(which is the callback passed into MyPromise), which calls `resolve` (which is the callback passed to `configFunction`), which calls `setTimeout`.

Comment: This is a really bad `Promise` implementation. I doesn't work at all like a real promise does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a correct Promise implementation. It clearly has no capabilities for rejections, but also for the implemented fulfilment feature it does not comply with the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/). Just to give two examples:

1. It does not comply with rule 2.1.2.2

   > When fulfilled, a promise must have a value, which must not change.

   ....nor with rule 2.2.2.3:

   > If `onFulfilled` is a function it must not be called more than once.

   In your implementation, if you would add a second call to `resolve`:

   ```
   new MyPromise(function(resolve, reject) {
     resolve('new message'); resolve('new message2');
   }).then((function(message) {
     console.log(message);
     // ... etc
   })
   ```

   ...then both calls to `resolve` would fire the `then` callback, and show that the promised value was modified after the first time it was set. This is in complete violation of the principle of promises: promises can only resolve once.
2. It does not comply with rule 2.2.6:

   > `then` may be called multiple times on the same promise.
   >
   > - If/when `promise` is fulfilled, all respective `onFulfilled` callbacks must execute in the order of their originating calls to `then`.

   This does not happen if we use the following code:

   ```
   let p = new MyPromise(resolve => resolve("value"));
   p.then(console.log); // This callback is called
   p.then(console.log); // This callback is not called -> violation!
   ```

These are basic shortcomings, and this is just the tip of the iceberg.

If you are interested in how it could be implemented in compliance with Promise/A+, then have a look [at one I did a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42057900/5459839) with a step-by-step explanation.

#### As to your question

> how does the program even get to the `setTimeout`?

When your main code executes this:

```
new MyPromise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('new message');
})
```

...then the parameter variable `configFunction` is initialised with that callback function. The `MyPromise` constructor *calls* it, passing it the following callback as first argument:

```
  function(message){
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(nextSuccessCallBack) {
        var result = nextSuccessCallBack(message);
        if(result && result.then) {
          result.then(nextResolve);
        } else {
          nextResolve && nextResolve(result);
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

So that means that `resolve` in your main code's callback function is initialised with the above callback function. Then your main code's callback function *calls* `resolve` with a string argument. Since `resolve` is the above callback function, we can see it gets executed with `message` initialised to "new message". This function executes `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the snippet does solve the purpose but, it is confusing as is a bad implementation of a `Promise` according to the way [MDN Uses Promises in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#basic_example) for better code efficiency and understanding.

The above code can also be written this way:

```
const examplePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("Another Message");
});

console.log("New Message");
examplePromise.then((message) => {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Now, for better understading of the concept of Promises in JavaScript, I'll take another example:

Let's say I want to create a program which says **hello** and then after 2 seconds says **How Are You?**

There are two ways of solving this

- Just using the `setTimeout()` function which executes a function after certain period of time
- Using promises with `setTimeout()`

Case I (Using [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)):

```
console.log("hello"); //Saying hello for the first time

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("How Are You?");
}, 2000); //2000 milliseconds is 2 seconds
```

Case II (Using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise))

```
console.log("hello");

const example = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("How Are You?");
    }, 2000);
});

example.then((message) => {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Now, for simple cases like logging a message after 2 seconds **do not require Promises**. You may use them (No problem) but actually, `Promises` are used in cases where, you wait for a function to execute a Database Query or you need to wait for a server to give you some HTML Response or while using WebAPIs, etc.

P.S: **`setTimeout()` is just an example.** It is not a rule that you always have to use `setTimeout()` while writing a `Promise`. If you are fetching data using a WebAPI, you usually write `$.ajax(...).then(...)` or `fetch(...).then(...)` instead of `setTimeout()`

Comment: What is the "*JavaScript Programming Guidelines*"? Also, I think the OP is trying to understand why *their* algorithm doesn't work, not that how to use the native one...

Comment: ...it won't just get lost, or? You can draft your question/answer as long as you want without it getting lost. SO also saves it to the local storage...