# How to write polyfill of promise which works for Promise.resolve()?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to write a promise polyfill to get a better understanding of promise.
I've searched the internet and found a code which I'm able to understand to some extent.

```
function CustomPromise(executor) {
var state=PENDING;
var value = null;
var handlers=[];
var catchers = [];

function resolve(result) {
    if(state!==PENDING) return;

    state=FULFILLED;
    value = result;

    handlers.forEach((h)=>h(value));    //this line
}

function reject(error) {
    if(state!==PENDING)return;

    state=REJECTED;
    value=error;
    catchers.forEach(c=>c(value));  // this line
}

this.then = function(successCallback) {
    if(state === FULFILLED) {
        successCallback(value);
    }else {
        handlers.push(successCallback);
    }
    return this;
}

this.catch = function(failureCallback) {
    if(state===REJECTED){
        failureCallback(value)
    } else {
        catchers.push(value);
    }
}
executor(resolve,reject);
}
```

Even in this I'm unable to understand the use of handlers and catchers. It was said that they are for situation when promise is not fulfilled or rejected. Explaining these two lines will also help.
Now, the actual issue with above implementation is it doesn't work for when used like `let p1 = Promise.resolve("Hello World");`. I have tried converting it to class based but I'm unable to do that.
My attempt:

```
class CustomPromise {
constructor(callback){
    this.state = PENDING;
    this.executor = callback;
    this.value = null;
    this.handlers = [];
    this.catchers = [];
    this.then = function(successCallback) {
        if(this.state === FULFILLED) {
            successCallback(this.value);
        }else {
            this.handlers.push(successCallback);
        }
        return this;
    };

    this.catch = function(failureCallback) {
        if(this.state===REJECTED){
            failureCallback(this.value)
        } else {
            this.catchers.push(this.value);
        }
    };
}

static resolve(result) {
    if(this.state!==PENDING) return;

    this.state=FULFILLED;
    this.value = result;

    this.handlers.forEach((h)=>h(this.value));
    // return new CustomPromise( function ( fulfil ) {
    //     fulfil( value );
    // });
}

static reject(error) {
    if(this.state!==PENDING)return;

    this.state=REJECTED;
    this.value=error;
    this.catchers.forEach(c=>c(this.value));
}

// executor(resolve,reject);
}
```

Can someone correct the functional approach so that it works for  `CustomPromise.resolve()` scenario or correction in my class based approach will also be appreciated.
EDIT: Tried `CustomPromise.prototype.resolve = function(error) {...}`
still getting same error `CustomPromise.resolve is not a function`
EDIT2 : In class based approach I'm unable to implement **executor** callback. I just want either one of the approach to work for case like `Promise.resolve()`

Comment: I agree this question could be closed, but I don't understand why this was closed with this dupe reference... @VLAZ? The asker already used `static` -- which is the right way to make their case work... The question is more about the *implementation* of that static method.

Comment: @trincot the "functional approach" mentioned (constructor function) doesn't work because the `resolve` and `reject` are not assigned as static methods. They are just functions declared inside but not visible outside.

Comment: Yes, but they already went to the `static` method further down the question... So how will the dupe reference help them??

Comment: @eras'q, your attempt in the static method that is put in comments, was the better one. Why did you put this in comments?

Comment: @trincot static approach was throwing same error.

Comment: @trincot In the class based approach I was unable to implement the executor callback, catchers, handlers.

Comment: @trincot "Can someone correct the functional approach so that it works for  CustomPromise.resolve() scenario" is what lead me to believe that's what the question is about. Upon re-reading it's really several questions related to the same issue but from completely different angles. And with several different problems. None of them especially explicit: "*I have tried converting it to class based but I'm unable to do that.*" isn't really specific to what goes wrong. The question should really just focus on one thing at a time and clarify what the problem is. Reopening, as it's not a dupe ATM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend the first (working) version of `CustomPromise`, add the code you seem to have been trying with in commented-out code in the (non-working) class-version you had. But it had two little problems. Still, the idea to use `new CustomPromise` is the right one:

```
CustomPromise.resolve = value => new CustomPromise(fulfil => fulfil(value));
CustomPromise.reject = error => new CustomPromise((_, reject) => reject(error));
```

So if you add that below your `CustomPromise` function definition, it'll work.

Secondly, as `catchers` is supposed to have callback functions, you should not push `value` to it, but `failureCallback`:

```js
const PENDING = "pending";
const FULFILLED = "fulfilled";
const REJECTED = "rejected";

function CustomPromise(executor) {
    var state=PENDING;
    var value = null;
    var handlers=[];
    var catchers = [];

    function resolve(result) {
        if(state!==PENDING) return;

        state=FULFILLED;
        value = result;

        handlers.forEach((h)=>h(value));
    }

    function reject(error) {
        if(state!==PENDING)return;

        state=REJECTED;
        value=error;
        catchers.forEach(c=>c(value));
    }

    this.then = function(successCallback) {
        if(state === FULFILLED) {
            successCallback(value);
        }else {
            handlers.push(successCallback);
        }
        return this;
    }

    this.catch = function(failureCallback) {
        if(state===REJECTED){
            failureCallback(value)
        } else {
            catchers.push(failureCallback); // Fix
        }
    }
    executor(resolve,reject);
}

// Added:
CustomPromise.resolve = value => new CustomPromise(fulfil => fulfil(value));
CustomPromise.reject = error => new CustomPromise((_, reject) => reject(error));

// Demo
let p = CustomPromise.resolve(42);
let q = CustomPromise.reject("custom error");
p.then(value => console.log("p", value));
q.catch(error => console.log("q", error));
```

Disclaimer: this polyfill is not compliant with the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/) let be it would be compliant with the ECMAScript specification for `Promise`.

Some of the problems it has:

- It allows the `then` callback to be executed synchronously. The `then` callback should never be executed synchronously, but always be called via a queued job (i.e. asynchronously).
- The `catch` method wrongly returns undefined. It should return a promise.
- The `then` method wrongly returns the same promise as it is called on. It should return a different promise, that resolves with the value that will be returned by the callback.
- The `then` method ignores a second argument. It should take a second function which should serve as a rejection callback (like `catch`).
- When the promise is resolved with a thenable, the thenable is wrongly used as fulfillment value. This is not how it is supposed to work. A very important aspect of promises, is that promises *chain*, i.e. when a promise resolves to another promise (or thenable), it gets "locked in" to that second promise, so that it will follow the way that second promise resolves.

There are many correct implementations to be found. I posted my own Promises/A+ compliant implementation [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772801/basic-javascript-promise-implementation-attempt/42057900#42057900). It does not have the `resolve` and `reject` static methods, but it would require the same additional code as given above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the reference. I have one doubt. `new CustomPromise((_, reject)` why did you add underscore as first parameter ?  because while invoking we only have one argument. `let q = CustomPromise.reject("custom error");`

Comment: The executor that we pass to `CustomerPromise` must be a function that accepts two callback functions. In the case of `.reject` we want to use the *second* argument that the executor will receive. Be aware that this executor is a completely different function, not to be confused with the `CustomPromise.reject` function, even though I have named that argument `reject` -- it is not this `CustomPromise.reject`.

Comment: Hi @trincot 
This is incorrect 
`catchers.push(value);`
This should be
`catchers.push(failureCallback); // `

Comment: @AnandParmar, indeed, I had not spotted that error in the asker's code. Thanks for spotting it! Updated.